# Connection to Weblogic JMS Queue fails

Tags: java, exception, jms, weblogic

I am trying to write a message to a JMS Queue running on Weblogic but I get a  java.rmi.ConnectIOException when trying to connect from a Eclipse program.

```
    javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException]
    at weblogic.jrmp.Context.lookup(Context.java:189)
    at weblogic.jrmp.Context.lookup(Context.java:195)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at example.jms.queue.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:42)
    at example.jms.queue.JMSSender.main(JMSSender.java:130)
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jrmp.BaseRemoteRef.invoke(BaseRemoteRef.java:221)
    at weblogic.jrmp.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jrmp.Context.lookup(Context.java:185)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at example.jms.queue.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:47)
    at example.jms.queue.JMSSender.main(JMSSender.java:130)
```

Below is my client program

```
package example.jms.queue;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.jms.*;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

/** This example shows how to establish a connection
* and send messages to the JMS queue. The classes in this
* package operate on the same JMS queue. Run the classes together to
* witness messages being sent and received, and to browse the queue
* for messages. The class is used to send messages to the queue.
*
* @author Copyright (c) 1999-2005 by BEA Systems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
*/
public class QueueSend
{
 // Defines the JNDI context factory.
 public final static String JNDI_FACTORY="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";

 // Defines the JMS context factory.
 public final static String JMS_FACTORY="jms/TestConnectionFactory";

 // Defines the queue.
 public final static String QUEUE="jms/TestJMSQueue";

 private QueueConnectionFactory qconFactory;
 private QueueConnection qcon;
 private QueueSession qsession;
 private QueueSender qsender;
 private Queue queue;
 private TextMessage msg;

 /**
  * Creates all the necessary objects for sending
  * messages to a JMS queue.
  *
  * @param ctx JNDI initial context
  * @param queueName name of queue
  * @exception NamingException if operation cannot be performed
  * @exception JMSException if JMS fails to initialize due to internal error
  */
 public void init(Context ctx, String queueName)
    throws NamingException, JMSException
 {
     System.out.println("1");
    qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
    System.out.println("1");
    qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();
    System.out.println("1");
    qsession = qcon.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    System.out.println("1");
    queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(queueName);
    qsender = qsession.createSender(queue);
    msg = qsession.createTextMessage();
    qcon.start();
 }

 /**
  * Sends a message to a JMS queue.
  *
  * @param message  message to be sent
  * @exception JMSException if JMS fails to send message due to internal error
  */
 public void send(String message) throws JMSException {
    msg.setText(message);
    qsender.send(msg);
 }

 /**
  * Closes JMS objects.
  * @exception JMSException if JMS fails to close objects due to internal error
  */
 public void close() throws JMSException {
    qsender.close();
    qsession.close();
    qcon.close();
 }
/** main() method.
 *
 * @param args WebLogic Server URL
 * @exception Exception if operation fails
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

     try{
         String url = "t3://localhost:7001";
            url = "http://127.0.0.1:7001/TestConnectionFactory/TestJMSQueue";
            //t://localhost:7001/ConnFact/QueueName
            InitialContext ic = getInitialContext(url);
            System.out.println("Hello");
            //System.out.println("cONTEXT----" + ic.lookup(url));
            QueueSend qs = new QueueSend();
            System.out.println("Initializing");
            qs.init(ic, QUEUE);
            System.out.println("Sending");
            readAndSend(qs);
            System.out.println("Sent");
            qs.close();
     }catch(Exception ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }

 }

 private static void readAndSend(QueueSend qs)
    throws IOException, JMSException
 {

    String line="Test string 123";

    // line = msgStream.readLine();

       qs.send(line);


 }

 private static InitialContext getInitialContext(String url)
    throws NamingException
 {
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    return new InitialContext(env);
 }
}
```

I have taken the code from a Oracle blog (https://blogs.oracle.com/soaproactive/entry/jms_step_2_using_the)

I see from the exception that the context lookup is failing, I cant suspect why ?

Comment: Have you checked the URL? why are you overwriting the URL variable in the try block in main method? pass the t3://localhost:7001 to getInitialContext()

Comment: @ManishKothari I tried with several URL's some with IP, some with localhost , some with HTTP but I get the same error all the time. 7001 is also the port on which I access the weblogic console. I somehow feel that it cannot be the port on which I should be writing the message.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this. The problem was because of some unwanted jars that I had added to the Project. Basically I had added all the Weblogic jars to my project. Later I removed all the Jars and just left wlclient.jar, wljmsclient.jar. I suspected Jar conflict while reading the article on https://redstack.wordpress.com/2009/12/21/a-simple-jms-client-for-weblogic-11g/.

Answer (score 1):

You only need this jar in classpath:

```
\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\wlclient.jar
```

Comment: Does this answer the question? If not, it may be better suited as a comment (which you currently lack the [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reputation) to make).